# Conversion of std::string to v8::string

Tags: v8

How can I convert std::string to v8::string,when I am trying to pass an std::string to a script in the following way

script1 = Script::Compile(param1);

I am getting conversion error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert a std::string to a v8::Local<v8::String>, you don't need to compile and run a script. Just do this:

```
std::string sText = "whatever";
v8::Local<v8::String> hTextJS = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), sText.c_str());
```

Comment: am getting this error: ‘NewFromUtf8’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’

Comment: v8::String::NewFromUtf8 is in the latest at https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h. Perhaps you have an old version? If you are using an older version, it might be called just v8::String::New.